# Android Speech Recognition needs a lot of time

Tags: android, speech

I followed this tutorial by androidhive:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Everything works fine !
But the Process needs a lot of time on my friends smartphone.But why ? 
Here's a example how it looks :

https://05526033536925262031.googlegroups.com/attach/d88261a5a349888d/Video_1.MOV?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGP4jYDxwbgNmyI7eOEafpbXauCkmrFy7hY3xCAMRKivHApsqHFOuIhLq8b8VBgbwbHB_ZG9b6Qcu9lVWPvOJLD9_gxYOXfe25RZHxEEgc7m8-HQw4

Any solutions ?

Comment: What does "needs a lot of time" mean? Are you talking about 5 seconds, 30 seconds, several minutes???

Comment: 10 Seconds after I ended my speech

Comment: It takes several seconds (possibly up to 4 or 5 seconds) for the "OK Google" app on my Nexus 7 to respond and that's using a high speed wi-fi connection to a router with a high speed broadband connection. Speech recognition isn't self-contained in Android and needs an external server to process it. If your friend's phone is connected using mobile internet then it will take some time to process.

Comment: But he downloaded the speech pack so he actually dont need it to download it from the internet

Comment: No it's not about downloading and installing the libray. The Speech To Text library works by using internet anyway.

Comment: Okay but we are using the same network so why do my smartphone found the end of the sentence and my friends one is waiting 10 seconds after he finishes his sentence  ?